# How to display only an excerpt of the content with custom post types?

Tags: templates, excerpt

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: second
*/
?>


<?php get_header(); ?>


<?php query_posts(array('post_type'=>'event')); ?>
    <?php if(have_posts()) while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="entry">
        <div class="thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?></div>
        <h1 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <div class="content page">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<div class="page-link">'.__('Pages', 'cpotheme').':', 'after' => '</div>')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>


<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The page acts like an index.php What should I amend in order to make the title as the link to the full page and make display only an excerpt of the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need two small changes (1st and 3rd lines), though I also took the liberty of tweaking the classes on the div to what seemed more appropriate:

```
<h1 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<div class="excerpt event">
   <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
   <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<div class="page-link">'.__('Pages', 'cpotheme').':', 'after' => '</div>')); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: The question is to display an excerpt for a paginated custom post types post pagination to each link.

Comment: I don't get that from reading it at all. Hopefully your answer is right.

Comment: Hm. Maybe you're right and he showed the code because he got exactly no clue :)

Comment: I did not mention pagination. This sorted out. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to form a html anchor tag using Wordpress functions, here's the example.

**Example -**

```
<h1 class="title">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( 'Permalink to %s', the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</h1>
```

And to display only excerpt there's functions called [`the_excerpt()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt)

Comment: The question is to display an excerpt for a paginated custom post types post pagination to each link.

Answer (score 0):

First off: **Interesting Question!**

Second: you need to add the `<!--nextpage-->` tag in your post one or multiple times. Else it won't work.

### The plugin:

What this plugin does is intercepting the output of `get_permalink()`, which is called internally by `wp_link_pages()`. Inside `get_permalink()`, we got the `get_post_permalink()` function that returns for custom post types. There we find the `'post_type_link'`-filter and this is where we hook in.

Then we take the `global $pages`, which holds an array of the post content splitted by the `<!--nextpage-->` HTML comment. Our static variable is a counter that helps us determining which part we should return - based on the times the function was called (starting at `0`).

The last thing is that we append this part from `$pages` to our post link. As the `esc_url()` function intercepts our permalink and would mess up all our Uppercase letters, spaces, etc., we attach a single firing filter there too and just return the original string.

```
<?php 
/** Plugin Name: (#67750) »kaiser« Append excerpt to post pagination */

/**
 * Callback for get_post_permalink() that is called by get_permalink() for
 * custom post types. We append the $GLOBALS['pages'][ $current ] excerpt here.
 * @param  string $post_link The original posts page link
 * @param  object $post The post object
 * @param  mixed boolean/string $leavename
 * @param  mixed boolean/string $sample A sample link
 * @return string $post_link
 */
function wpse67750_pagination_excerpt( $post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample )
{
    if (
        'YOUR_POST_TYPE' !== get_post_type()
        OR ! in_the_loop()
        OR ! is_singular()
    )
        return;

    static $n = 0;
    // The global pages array: Contains the current post type pages
    global $pages;

    // We need a callback to reserve the original appended string
    // not messed up by the esc_url() function.
    add_filter( 'clean_url', 'wpse67750_pagination_url_cb', 10, 3 );

    // The current page content
    $curr = $pages[ $n++ ];

    // Build the output
    // Wrap it up for easy targeting via CSS and JS
    // Also append a non visible single HTML tag to allow closing the still open anchor
    $output = sprintf(
         '"> %s <span class="excerpt" id="page-%s">%s</span><a style="display:none" rel="nofollow" href="#'
        ,$n
        ,$n
        ,trim( $curr )
    );
    /*$output = apply_filters(
         'the_excerpt'
        ,$output
    );*/

    // Append to the link
    return $post_link.$output;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpse67750_pagination_excerpt', 10, 4 );

/**
 * The callback to preserve the string appended to the permalink
 * @param  string $url Escaped
 * @param  string $orig_url Not escaped
 * @param  string $context 'display'
 */
function wpse67750_pagination_url_cb( $url, $orig_url, $context )
{
    // Only run once
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // Return the non escaped original
    return $orig_url;
}
```

The solution is not completely perfect. I hadn't got around getting rid of the first number and there seems to be a slight problem with retrieving the last link in some cases. It also had the problem, that core doesn't offer a possibility to get rid of the appended `</a>` closing tag, so I had to add *fake* links there. Those don't get displayed, won't be followed by search engines and don't harm. They're just not beautiful, but that's the only possibility.